# Module productive minds SiteSwitcher and changing countries

Tags: module, multicurrency, country-regions, countries

I have this module currently installed and when i use the top drop down Change Language it switches to the correct store utilizing the correct language and currency. No problem here, see picture below.

[image: Change Language]

The second drop down change country on the other hand does nothing at all.

[image: Change Country]

Now on to what I'm trying to accomplish. So i've been trying to add a few new countries to the list when someone changes country. Here are a few:

[image: Other possible countries i would like to add]

I'm currently working in the `Lib/zend/locale/data/en.xml`

Am I working in the wrong file? It seems to have all the standard countries etc...  but when i select anything on the frontend from "Change Country" it just defaults back to the US. Please help. Thank you.

I will post xml file if needed.